# javascript function not called from django-forms

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a validation error. This javascript function is not at all being called. My code:

```
<form action="." onsubmit="return myform()" name="myform" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Buy">
</form>
<script>
    function myform()
    {
            var nam = document.forms["myform"]["name"];
            alert('Checking');
            if(some_condition)
            {
                   alert("Sorry. Some Error");
                   return false;
            }
            return true;
    }
</script>
```

Event the `alert('Checking)` does not work. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Function name mismatching. it is not `buyform()` change into `myform()`

you need to use `getElementsByName`

```
 document.forms["myform"].getElementsByName('name');
```

Can you change the function name like "myValidateform"

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FNBS5/1/

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName

Comment: Sorry. That was not the mistake. It was a typing mistake

Comment: But that function itself is not executing. I should get the `checking` alert right?

Comment: It is showing  an error, thats is the reason function not executed

Comment: Updated my answer and demo, can you please check

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<form action="javascript:myform()" name="myform" method="post">

    <input type="submit" value="Buy"/>
</form>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FNBS5/)

Comment: But what about returning to my django view after validation?